# Python, class dataset, how to concatenate images with their respective labels in pytorch

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am new to PyTorch, and in the last couple of days I have been struggling with the class Dataset that lets you build your custom dataset.

I am working with this dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/ianmoone0617/flower-goggle-tpu-classification/kernels) , the problem is that it has the images and their labels in separate folders, and I can’t figure out how to concatenate them.

This is the code I am using:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.labels = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if torch.is_tensor(index):
            index = index.tolist()

        image_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.labels.iloc[index, 0])
        image = io.imread(image_name)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return (image, labels)
```

While the structure of the folders is the following one: 
[image: structure of the folders]]

I really want to understand this so thank you in advance guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're nearly there. There are many ways to deal with this. For example, you could read both csv files during initialization to build a dictionary which maps the label string in the `flowers_idx.csv` to the label index specified in `flowers_label.csv`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torchvision.datasets.folder import default_loader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_csv, label_csv, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.data_entries = pd.read_csv(data_csv)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

        label_map = pd.read_csv(label_csv)
        self.label_str_to_idx = {label_str: label_idx for label_idx, label_str in label_map.iloc}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if torch.is_tensor(index):
            index = index.item()

        label = self.label_str_to_idx[self.data_entries.iloc[index, 1]] 
        image_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, f'{self.data_entries.iloc[index, 0]}.jpeg')

        # torchvision datasets generally return PIL image rather than numpy ndarray
        image = default_loader(image_path)

        # alternative to load ndarray using skimage.io
        # image = io.imread(image_path)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return (image, label)
```

Note that this returns `PIL` images rather than ndarrays since that's generally what is returned by torchvision datasets. This is also nice since many of the torchvision transforms can only be appled to PIL images.

For now a simple use case could be:

```
import torchvision.transforms as tt

dataset_dir = '/home/jodag/datasets/527293_966816_bundle_archive'
# TODO add more transforms/data-augmentation etc...
transform = tt.Compose((
    tt.ToTensor(),
))

dataset = MyDataset(
    os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'flowers_idx.csv'),
    os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'flowers_label.csv'),
    os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'flower_tpu/flower_tpu/flowers_google/flowers_google'),
    transform)

image, label = dataset[0]
```

During training or validation you would probably use a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) to sample the dataset.

Comment: Hey Man thank you so much, I am so grateful to you!! Thanks to your suggestions I understood how to build the class! One last thing I tried to implement the class without using your code and it worked, but at the end when I try to evaluate the model, it gives me back an error saying that "tuple object has no attribute size". I think that the problem is the fact that in the class dataset, as the labels I did not map them with a dictionary, I just used the labels from the flowers_idx.csv, which are strings. Is there a way to fix this, in case I didn't have the other file, flowers_label.csv?